# SilverLight : system.servicemodel.domainservices.client.domainoperationexception

Tags: silverlight

I am currently facing a problem when run the **Silverlight Project.**

which i have downloaded from [This Link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/3cf852/authentication-against-custom-table-in-silverlight-4-using-ria-service/) .

But when i run the project it shows me following Dialogue box

What should be the problem....please suggest me.....please help me friends...i googled much but it can't helps me..

Thank you so much friends...

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please change the connection string for using own SQL Server, like this:

```
<connectionStrings><add name="StatsOfIndiaEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataModel_SOI.csdl|res://*/DataModel_SOI.ssdl|res://*/DataModel_SOI.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\StatsOfIndia.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

I use SQLExpress on my working machine.

Comment: I have already did that.....but it doesn't helps me.... thank you so much for answering

Comment: Try check connection string in Server Explorer and set a Web project as StartUp project and rebuild the all solution.

Comment: i have exactly did the same but it doesn't helps me

Comment: I did same and it works fine. Try update Entity Models, rebuild project and run again. If it will work then you should update a version of Entity Framework.

Comment: I have Changed connection string to this==> <connectionStrings>
    <add name="StatsOfIndiaEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataModel_SOI.csdl|res://*/DataModel_SOI.ssdl|res://*/DataModel_SOI.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=PRITESHARYAN-PC\PRITESHB_ARYAN;Initial Catalog=STATSOFINDIA.MDF;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>                                                               and it works fine now.......